# Getting specific numbers from a text file containing a mix of alphanumeric characters in python

Tags: python, csv, text-mining

I have a `.txt` file that looks like this but much longer:

```
Image0001_01.tif[1] <- Image0035_01.tif[1]: (410.0, -362.0) correlation (R)=0.05516124 (176 ms)
Image0001_01.tif[1] <- Image0002_01.tif[1]: (489.0, -495.0) correlation (R)=0.047715914 (287 ms)
Image0002_01.tif[1] <- Image0003_01.tif[1]: (647.0, 0.0) correlation (R)=0.8842946 (295 ms)
Image0001_01.tif[1] <- Image0036_01.tif[1]: (265.0, -363.0) correlation (R)=0.039207384 (365 ms)
Image0002_01.tif[1] <- Image0034_01.tif[1]: (626.0, -626.0) correlation (R)=0.60634625 (124 ms)
...........
```

I'd like to turn this into a comma separated file (csv) so that I can look at the correlations (R-values) but running into problems because of the weird formatting of this file. Is there a way I can do this in Python?

Comment: what to you want as output? what have you tried? please help us help you :) looks like a simple use of `re`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **re** and **csv** in python to parse your file and convert it to a csv file:

```
import re
import csv

re_expression = '^(.*?) <- (.*?): \((.*?), (.*?)\) correlation \(R\)=(.*?) \((.*?) ms\)$'

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    outfile = csv.writer(csvfile)
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break
            m = re.split(re_expression, line)
            outfile.writerow(m[1:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Running the code I get the following error:ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 10             m = re.split(re_expression, f.readlines())
     11             outfile.writerow(m[1:-1])
     12 

ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: I've updated my answer to prevent this problem (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826493/python-mixing-files-and-loops)

Comment: ---> 10             line = original.readline()  NameError: name 'original' is not defined

Comment: very strange: now I get this error: ---> 10             line = original.readline() "I/O operation on closed file"

Comment: Should be fixed now, the variables weren't correct.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced rb with wb in the csvfile line as well as added rb after 'input.txt' because it was throwing a can't write to file error. Now the code throws no errors but when I open the output.csv it has actually not done anything to the file.

Comment: Take a look now - the open should be just 'w' with the newline option as well to avoid extra line breaks.

Comment: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95495/discussion-between-kponz-and-v-ix).