# Zero size length on json object in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm not sure why this happen, there are zero length in my json file.

```
0
```

I t supposedly to be like this,

```
1000
```

I'm afraid the `comma` thing after each json object cause this issue. (My current json format)

```
{ A:"A"},{ B:"B"),...
```

The correct way is like this

```
{ A:"A"} { B:"B"),...
```

So how I can calculate all the length without removing the `comma`?

My code

```
import json

githubusers_data_path = 'githubusers.json'

githubusers_data = []
githubusers_file = open(githubusers_data_path, "r")
for line in githubusers_file:
    try:
        data = json.loads(line)
        githubusers_data.append(data)
    except:
        continue

print len(githubusers_data)
```

Sample

```
{
    "login": "datomnurdin"
}, {
    "login": "ejamesc"
},...
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do but your code fails on `data = json.loads(line)`. This is because you read the file line by line and none of the lines `{`, `"login": "datomnurdin"`, `}, {`, etc. are valid JSONs. I suppose you wanted to do `data = json.load(githubusers_file)` (note no "s" in "load").

Comment: Verify that your json is valid by running it through a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @freakish Already test it. still 0 length.

Comment: @Kamehameha It's valid 101%.

Comment: The sample json you posted isn't valid json. I ran it through http://jsonlint.com/ (removed the dots obviously).

Comment: @ArnabDatta I'm not sure it's a sarcasm or not, the 'dot' thing shows more than 2 json objects. I hope u understand that.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin : nope, no sarcasm. The validator claimed it wasn't valid json. I think for it to be valid json, you need one top-level object only and if it's in the format you described, then you have more than one.

Comment: In the future, use `except Exception as e` and print `e` for information when it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting an exception that you're suppressing with try-except, because of the commas.
One solution would be to convert your file to a string first, stick a '[' and ']' around the string to convert it into a valid `json` format, then use `json.loads` to convert the string.

```
import json

githubusers_data_path = 'githubusers.json'

githubusers_file = open(githubusers_data_path, "r")
githubusers_string = ''.join(line for line in githubusers_file)
githubusers_string = '[{}]'.format(githubusers_string)
githubusers_data = json.loads(githubusers_string)

print len(githubusers_data)
githubusers_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an exception in your code:

```
import json

githubusers_data_path = 'githubusers.json'

githubusers_data = []
githubusers_file = open(githubusers_data_path, "r")
for line in githubusers_file:
    try:
        data = json.load(githubusers_file) # exception from here
        githubusers_data.append(data)
    except Exception, e:
        print e

print len(githubusers_data) # so githubusers_data is always []
```

[Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826493/python-mixing-files-and-loops)

Comment: your suggestion I got Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data error message. but the length still 0.